# JS/React - returning a function instead of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to return an array (GET_NUMBERS action) but the reducer seems to be returning a function. It's probably not even related to React/Redux but just javascript error. I just want 'numbers' to return an array of 10 elements. If 'shuffled' is an array, and I'm returning 'shuffled', why is the action returning a function? Please advise. Thank you very much in advance.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const genArray = () => {
  let numbers = new Array(10);
  const shuffled = [];

  numbers = numbers.fill(1).map((_, i) => i + 1);

  while (numbers.length) {
    const idx = numbers.length * Math.random() | 0;
    shuffled.push(numbers[idx]);
    numbers.splice(idx, 1);
  }
  return shuffled;
};

const numbers = genArray();
console.log(numbers);
console.log(typeof numbers);

const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  numbers
};

const countReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return {
        count: state.count + 1
      };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return {
        count: state.count - 1
      };
    case 'ZERO':
      return {
        count: 0
      };
    case 'POWER':
      return {
        count: Math.pow(state.count, 2)
      };
    case 'GET_NUMBERS':
      return {
        numbers: state.numbers
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default createStore(countReducer);
```

EDIT: addition:

The reason I think it returns a function is the fact that in my Container, the only time I don't have a warning of mismatch is when I use a 'func' on numbers:

```
Counter.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number,
  numbers: PropTypes.func,
  increment: PropTypes.func,
  decrement: PropTypes.func,
  zero: PropTypes.func,
  power: PropTypes.func
};
```

I've tried doing PropTypes.array but I get:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `numbers` of type `function`
>   supplied to `Counter`, expected `array`.

index.ios.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

import store from './src/store';
import Counter from './src/Counter';
import * as actions from './src/actions';

// map the state k
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  count: state.count,
  numbers: state.numbers
});

const CounterContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Counter);

const Countly = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CounterContainer />
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Countly', () => Countly);
```

actions.js

```
export const increment = () => {
  const action = {
    type: 'INCREMENT'
  };
  return action;
};

export const decrement = () => {
  const action = {
    type: 'DECREMENT'
  };
  return action;
};

export const zero = () => {
  const action = {
    type: 'ZERO'
  };
  return action;
};

export const power = () => {
  const action = {
    type: 'POWER'
  };
  return action;
};

export const numbers = () => {
  const action = {
    type: 'GET_NUMBERS'
  };
  return action;
};
```

Counter.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class Counter extends React.Component {

  renderNumbers() {
    console.log(this.props.numbers);
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.numbers}</Text>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.appName}>
          Countly
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.tally}>
          Tally: {this.props.count}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.tally}>
          Numbers: {this.renderNumbers()}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.increment} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            +
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.decrement} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            -
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.power} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            pow
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.zero} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            0
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number,
  numbers: PropTypes.func,
  increment: PropTypes.func,
  decrement: PropTypes.func,
  zero: PropTypes.func,
  power: PropTypes.func
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  appName: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  tally: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 25
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: 100,
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 20
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

Comment: how are can you say that it's return a function? from which part?

Comment: I"m not understanding the point of your reducer for GET_NUMBERS. Reducers should be a change to state based on user action. In this case you are just returning the preexisting state of numbers so it seems to me what you are really wanting to do is just access `this.state.numbers` when you do your `mapStateToProps` on whatever your container component is. When you dispatch an action the return value is the function https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/61

Comment: @Wasteland, remember that `typeof [] === 'object'` (array is an object in JavaScript). If you want to check if an object is an Array, you can use [`Array.isArray(numbers)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). I copied/pasted your snippet here and looks correct to me: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/nbgrxvu5/ (check the console)

Comment: @finalfreq, I see what you mean. I just want to get it work like that, step by step, and then will modify it to change the state. Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the things in the link. Are you saying it's the expected behaviour to return a function and that's how it works? By the way, I added something to my question above.

Comment: You might want to include code for how you are passing the props to the `<Counter>` component and also how you are dispatching the GET_NUMBERS action.

Comment: added the rest of the code

Comment: cheeky bump..no one?